Adding vectorized data to an AI chatbot in Python
I'm trying to add vectorized data (file format .npz) to my Azure OpenAI chatbot in order to make it generate answers based on this data.
The thing is I tried watching various videos but none helped me in any way.
import os
import numpy as np
import faiss
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import openai
import asyncio
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

load_dotenv()

AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY = os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY']
AZURE_OPENAI_API_ENDPOINT = os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_API_ENDPOINT']
AZURE_OPENAI_API_MODEL = os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_API_MODEL']
AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION = os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION']

openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_key = AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY
openai.api_base = AZURE_OPENAI_API_ENDPOINT
openai.api_version = AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION

var_temperature = 0.7 
var_top_p = 0.95
var_max_tokens = 800
var_frequency_penalty = 0
var_presence_penalty = 0
var_past_messages_included = 10

system_message = "Your name is Bot. Answer as concisely and politely as possible."
system_message_chunk = [{"role": "system", "content": system_message}]

few_shot_chunk = []
chat_history_chunk = []

def load_vector_data(file_path="combined_vectors.npz"):
    data = np.load(file_path)
    vectors = data['vectors']
    ids = data['ids']
    index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(vectors.shape[1])
    index.add(vectors)
    return index, ids

def find_relevant_data(user_input_vector, index, all_ids):
    D, I = index.search(np.array([user_input_vector]), k=1)
    closest_id = all_ids[I[0][0]]
    return closest_id

async def chat_with_bot(user_input, index, all_ids, model):
    global chat_history_chunk
    user_input_vector = model.encode([user_input])[0]
    relevant_id = find_relevant_data(user_input_vector, index, all_ids)
    relevant_content = f"Contextual information related to ID: {relevant_id}"
    chat_history_chunk.append({"role": "system", "content": relevant_content})
    chat_history_chunk.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})

    if len(chat_history_chunk) > var_past_messages_included:
        chat_history_chunk = chat_history_chunk[-var_past_messages_included:]

    messages = system_message_chunk + few_shot_chunk + chat_history_chunk

    response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
        deployment_id=AZURE_OPENAI_API_MODEL,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=var_temperature,
        max_tokens=var_max_tokens,
        top_p=var_top_p,
        frequency_penalty=var_frequency_penalty,
        presence_penalty=var_presence_penalty
    )

    chat_history_chunk.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response['choices'][0]['message']['content']})
    return response['choices'][0]['message']['content']

async def main():
    index, all_ids = load_vector_data()
    model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        if user_input.lower() == "exit":
            break

        response = await chat_with_bot(user_input, index, all_ids, model)
        print(f"Bot: {response}")

asyncio.run(main())

I tried with this code, but the bot doesn't react to this data at all. Perhaps it can't read it in vectorized format? It's my first time using vectorized data so perhaps I just don't understand something?

It looks like you are adding the vector ID to the message and not the content of the vector. Try adding the content of the most relevant vector instead of the ID.
